# add another objects on click django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have an object with name, surname and email and I have a button that when clicked should create another empty object for me to fill in and then with another button create the two objects in the database.

How can I create the event that generates a new object for me?

Comment: What type object you are using ? Is it Model object or Form object or just simple python object ?

Comment: It can be done using some ajax logic and Formsets. See [this](https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html) for idea.

Comment: I have a form that should save data in a template, it works but only with one object if I create more it only saves the last filled object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have Model like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

Assuming you have some generic form (You can use model forms too).

```
from django import forms

class PersonForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

Now you have to create [FormSet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/#django.forms.formsets.BaseFormSet) form object as it allows to store multiple form.

forms.py

```
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet
class BasePersonFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def clean(self):

        if any(self.errors):
            return
        
        emails = []
        duplicates = False

        for form in self.forms:
            if form.cleaned_data:
                first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']

                # Validation logic, you can change accordingly
                # 1. Checking if first_name and email is present in response
                if not first_name:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Please provide first name.',
                        code='missing_first_name'
                    )
                elif not last_name:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Please provide last name.',
                        code='missing_last_name'
                    )

                elif not email:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Please provide email.',
                        code='missing_URL'
                    )

                # 2. Checking if multiple persons have same emails
                if email:
                    if email in emails:
                        duplicates = True
                    emails.append(email)

                if duplicates:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        'Email must be unique for each person.',
                        code='duplicate_email'
                    )
```

If you are using jquery then [this](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) plugin might be useful, else you have to write your own ajax logic to manipulate the add and remove logic.

Just add the `jquery.formset.js` from [here](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/src/jquery.formset.js) to your static files folder so that we can use it in template.

Now your view controller might look something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import PersonForm,BasePersonFormSet
from .models import Person

# Create your views here.
def view_method(request):
    # Create the formset, specifying the form and formset.
    PersonFormSet = formset_factory(PersonForm, formset=BasePersonFormSet)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        person_formset = PersonFormSet(request.POST)

        if person_formset.is_valid():

            # Now save the data for each form in the formset
            new_persons = []

            for link_form in person_formset:
                first_name = link_form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
                last_name = link_form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
                email = link_form.cleaned_data.get('email')

                if first_name and email:
                    new_persons.append(Person(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email))

            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    #Adding multiple objects
                    Person.objects.bulk_create(new_persons)

                    # And notify our users that it worked
                    messages.success(request, 'You have added multiple Person objects.')

            except IntegrityError: #If the transaction failed
                messages.error(request, 'There was an error while creating multiple Person objects.')
                return render(request,'multifield_formset/error_template.html')

    else:
        person_formset = PersonFormSet()

    context = {
        'person_formset': person_formset,
    }

    return render(request, 'multifield_formset/template.html', context)
```

And your template.html file as follows:

```
{% load static %}

{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ person_formset.management_form }}

    {% for person_form in person_formset %}
        <div class="person-formset">
            {{ person_form.first_name }}
            {% if person_form.first_name.errors %}
                {% for error in person_form.first_name.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ person_form.last_name }}
            {% if person_form.last_name.errors %}
                {% for error in person_form.last_name.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ person_form.email }}
            {% if person_form.email.errors %}
                {% for error in person_form.email.errors %}
                    {{ error|escape }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if person_formset.non_form_errors %}
        {% for error in person_formset.non_form_errors %}
            {{ error|escape }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit form" class="button"/>
</form>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
<script>
    $('.person-formset').formset({
        addText: 'add person',
        deleteText: 'remove'
    });
</script>
```

Credits: I used [this reference](https://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html) to create following solution.

Comment: thank you very much, but if I refresh the page the objects I add disappear, is there a way to keep them always even if I refresh?

Answer (score 0):

you can create this with ajax, but this is not much effective, you need create a object with a form ever following the doc

Comment: in what way? I have a form that saves the data in my template